# Laravel Migrations: trouble with documentation and incorrect types

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I started to use Laravel framework and I have a question about its documentation.

For example, I want to make the field unique.

First, I found **very short introduction** about migrations here: http://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations

Next, I opened API docs (http://laravel.com/api/master/index.html) and looked for `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` class. Then I used its `string` method which returns `Illuminate\Support\Fluent`:

```
 $table->string('name', 64)->unique();
```

Fluent doesn't have `unique` method, but the method works.
Why Laravel developers return incorrect types?

And how can I find these methods like `unique`? Documentation is very scarce, interface is incorrect.

P.S. Laravel 5, but same problem exists in Laravel 4.

Answer (score 1):

The docs are here: http://laravel.com/docs/master/schema

Here's how Fluent works: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Fluent.php#L134-L146